# How to create Composite-key for a Model in lift's mapper?

Tags: scala, lift, mapper

Does mapper allows creation of composite key in Models ? If yes, kindly give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one example:

```
class FooBar extends LongKeyedMapper[FooBar] { 
  def getSingleton = FooBar 
  def primaryKeyField = id 
  object id extends MappedLongIndex(this) 
  object foo extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, Foo) 
  object bar extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, Bar) 
} 

object FooBar extends FooBar with LogKeyedMetaMapper[FooBar] { 
  override def dbIndexes = Index(foo, bar) :: super.dbIndexes 
}
```

Example taken from the [Lift mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/a783124e3e2490b4)

Comment: "override def dbIndexes" in the last line. simple def dbIndexes will not work