# Compound PrimaryKey in Mapper

Tags: scala, lift, mapper

I'm actually working with scala lift. I need to set a compound PK with Mapper, and from what I saw in the web (links below) its not possible. How can I do this?

Links:

- [How to create Composite-key for a Model in lift's mapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047176/how-to-create-composite-key-for-a-model-in-lifts-mapper)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/liftweb/p4MSTj4kkLQ

Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, it's not possible.
Simple solution: don't use lift-mapper. :) 
I believe Slick can do composite primary keys.

Comment: Squeryl supports composite keys as well.